How to apply CalibratedClassifierCV to the external validation of a Random Forest model?
I have a model trained on my data. I used JobLib to get the model and shared it with other teams to evaluate the performance of the model on their data. One of the team members came back and said that the models are not very well calibrated, so I thought of suggesting they apply isotonic regression. The team only has 1 dataset, which they do not want to split. Shall I use Prefit (as below), and will it lead to overfitting or any other problem? Is there any other way to apply isotonic regression? I also don't want to apply isotonic regression to my model and then send it to them because the model is working fine for other teams.
calibrated_rf_isotonic_prefit = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=pretrained_model, method='isotonic', cv='prefit')
calibrated_rf_isotonic_prefit.fit(X, y)


Tell us about the Business Domain. You have not described why you believe one class of hypotheses is better suited to it than another class. Choosing an inappropriate family of hypothesis functions induces unwanted bias. How does the use case at hand relate to monotonicity?

The domain is healthcare. Once I know how to apply isotonic regression, I can try other regressions like platt as well.
